# Логирование в окне приложения в TextBox приводит к тормозам приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет. Делаю приложение, в котором присутствует "живой лог" - т.е. при работе определенных частей кода пишутся данные.
Код в xaml выглядит так:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Log}"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DimGray"
         Background="WhiteSmoke"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         TextChanged="Log_OnTextChanged"></TextBox>
```

В обработчике события TextChanged я пытался сделать очистку:

```
private void Log_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox tb)
    {
        tb.ScrollToEnd();
        if (tb.Text.Length > 100000)
        {
            tb.Text = string.Empty;
            tb.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + ": " + "Clear log" + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Само свойств, забинденное на Text не обладает ничем особенным:

```
/// <summary>Лог текущей сессии</summary>
public string Log
{
    get => _log;
    set
    {
        if (Equals(_log, value)) return;
        _log = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что в лог пишется много текста и когда его набирается уже на пару десятков строк, то окно уже начинает тормозить жутко при перемещении или изменении размера окна.
И что странно - после срабатывания метода Log_OnTextChanged лог вообще перестает писаться ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Как лучше всего реализовать логирование в окне приложения?

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:**

Наверное стоит упомянуть про важные моменты. Во ViewModel моего окна есть метод:

```
/// <summary>Отправка сообщения в лог</summary>
/// <param name="msg">Текст сообщения</param>
private void SendMessageToLog(string msg)
{
    Log += DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": " + msg + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Основная работа приложения идет в статическом классе. После запуска приложения требуется "стартануть" работу этого класса. В классе есть делегат

```
public Action<string> ShowCallbackMessageAction { get; set; }
```

А при "старте" класса запускается асинхронный метод с бесконечным Task внутри которого отправляются сообщения через делегат. Типа того:

```
private async void CheckClientsConnectionLoop()
{
    while (!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        ShowCallbackMessageAction?.Invoke("Some message to log");
        CheckClientsConnection();

        await Task.Delay(10000, _cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task => { });
    }
}
```

Снаружи (во viewmodel) я подписываюсь на делегат своим методом логирования:

```
LicenseServer.Instance.ShowCallbackMessageAction = SendMessageToLog;
```

Comment: Логику по очистке сделайте в сеттере вашего свойства Log, это должно полечить проблему с "перестает писаться". А так - любой контрол с виртуализацией должен работать шустро. Лучше бы профилировать, что именно тормозит.

Comment: Логику по очистке заменил - запустил на тестирование. Я еще, наверное, важные моменты не добавил в вопрос. Сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: `Как лучше всего реализовать логирование в окне приложения?` - Создаете коллекцию (`public ObservableCollection<string> Logs {get;set;}`), в View делаете `ItemsControl`/`ListBox` и привязываете его к коллекции. Если надо удалять старые значения, то при инициализации ObservableCollection подпишитесь на его событие изменения и в нем удаляйте старые значения.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Сейчас опробую

Comment: Отлично зашло с ObservableCollection! Тормоза исчезли. Единственная загвоздка - нужно найти как скролить ListBox при каждом обновлении коллекции

Comment: @АлександрПекшев Примерно [так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16866309/6808809). P.S. Не забывайте указывать через `@` имя того, кому этот комментарий, ибо без этого оповещение может не придти и человек попросту не узнает о вашем сообщение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо. Я новичок на StackOverflow - как-то не подумал

Comment: Также я вам советую, что бы такого не было `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": " + msg` - сделать вместо string - свой класс в котором создать нужные свойства и в Xaml уже в нужном виде выводить (переопределив шаблон Item'a). Вот к примеру [так](https://pastebin.com/TjA7cvub) я думаю стоит реализовать.

Comment: Ну или [так](http://geekswithblogs.net/tamir/archive/2008/11/10/auto-scroll-listbox-in-wpf.aspx) более WPF-way